# Understanding error in oop Backprop implementation

Tags: backpropagation, softmax

Good evening everybody.
I have been using NN quite often already, so I thought it's time to face the background.
As a result I have been spending quite a lot of hours with my c++ implementation of a Neural Network from scratch. Still, I do not get any useful output.

My issue is the clean OOP and efficient implementation, especially what I have to backpropagate from one Layer class to the next. I am aware that I'm just skipping the full calculation/forwarding of the jacobian matrices, but from my understanding this isn't necessary, since most of the entries will be cut out.

**I have a softmax class with size n:**

Forward Pass: It takes an input vector input of length n and creates an output vector output of size n.
`sum = 0; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += e^input[ i ].`
Then it calculates an output vector output of length n with:
`output [ i ] = e^input [ i ] / sum`

Backward Pass: It takes a feedback vector target of size n, the target value.
I do not have weights or biase in my softmax class, so I just calculate the feedback vector feedback of size n:
`feedback[ i ] = output[ i ] - target[ i ]`
That is what I return from my softmax layer.

**I have a fully Connected class: m -> n**

Forward Pass: It take an input vector of size m.
I calculate the net activity vector net of size n, and an output vector of size n:
`net[ i ] = b[ i ];`
`for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) net[ i ] += w[ i ][ j ] * input[ i ]`
`output [ i ] = 1 / (1 + e^-net[ i ])`

Backward Pass: It takes an feedback vector of size n from the following layer.
`b'[ i ] = b[ i ] + feedback[ i ] * 1 * learningRate`
`w'[ i ][ j ] = w[ i ][ j ] + feedback[ i ] * input[ j ] * learningRate`
The new feedback array of size m:
`feedback'[ i ] = 0;`
`feedback'[ i ] += feedback[ j ] * weights[ i ][ j ] * (output[ j ] * (1 - output[ j ]))`

Of course, the feedback from one fully connected layer will be passed to the next, and so on.
I've been reading a few articles and found this one quite nice:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pjsadows/notes.pdf

I feel like my implementation should be identical to what I read in such papers, but even after a small number of training examples (~100) my network output is getting close to a constant. Basically as if it would be just depending on the biase.

So, could someone please give me a hint if I'm wrong with my theoretical understanding, or if I just have some issues with my implementation?